# Are there no unique battle maps for special cities in the Total War: ROME II campaign?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I recently attacked the city of Alexandria with a combined naval and land force in my co-op campaign with a friend, and was looking forward to a battle in the environment presented on this page: http://wiki.totalwar.com/w/Total_War_ROME_II:_Capital_Cities

However, when the battle map loaded the city looked nothing like the one in the picture of Alexandria in the wiki. It was just a generic coastal city with walls, no huge lighthouse or other unique details.

From the wiki page (emphasis added):

> Among all the settlements and cities to be found as you conquer your way across ROME II’s **campaign map**, five stand out as great wonders of engineering [...]

and

> It’s only right that the battle maps for these mighty seats of ancient civilisation get the special treatment, so we’ve gone to town on making them the most intricate, stunning, authentic and of course epic cityscapes we’ve ever created.

I also attacked Carthage earlier during the campaign and as I recall it too didn't look any different from the other generic provincial capitals I had waged battles in.

Is there anyone who has attacked or defended one of these "unique" capitals and had the battle map actually look like the cities in the pictures on the wiki page?

Comment: To be honest, I was really disappointed about the so-called unique cities. I had conquered one tough looking barbarian capital, converted it into a Roman one, and once the convertion was completed, it had changed into your average generic Roman capital.

Comment: The devs said a lot of things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the guys at CA said that the city had to be upgraded to max 
to make it look like in your pic.

Though truth is they did a really lazy and poor job creating this game.
Rushed and unfinished.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, although I haven't been able to confirm it myself. Nevertheless I will check this as the correct answer for now. Thanks!